# ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION AndroidManifest Permissions Not Being Granted

Tags: android, permissions, gps, location, android-manifest

I am trying to utilize GPS in Android (2.2 and 2.3) but am getting the following error when I try to use the LocationManager object:

`WARN/System.err(522): java.lang.SecurityException: Provider network requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission`

I have researched the issue in other posts and they are typically due to issues with AndroidManifest.xml.  However, mine appears to be fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.thedigitalsean.examples"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".GetLocation"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Here is the offending line of code in my onCreate method in the GetLocation Activity, encased in a try/catch block:

```
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final LocationListener locListener = new MyLocListener();

    try{
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
    }
    catch (SecurityException se){
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.infobox)).setText(se.toString());
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the first app I have written where I need to request android permissions and have so far been unsuccessful in being granted any permissions whatsoever.  Is there something I am missing in my manifest or perhaps in my eclipse configuration?

Comment: Pls recheck answers

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You misspelled permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Embarrassing, but that was it.  Thanks!

Comment: then why it is not accessing,in marshmaellow even if u have given all the permission in manifest.

Answer (score 22):

I was having the same problem and could not figure out what I was doing wrong.  Turns out, the auto-complete for Android Studio was changing the text to either all caps or all lower case (depending on whether I typed in upper case or lower cast words before the auto-complete).  The OS was not registering the name due to this issue and I would get the error regarding a missing permission.  As stated above, ensure your permissions are labeled correctly:

**Correct**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**Incorrect**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**Incorrect**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.access_fine_location" />
```

Though this may seem trivial, its easy to overlook.

If there is some setting to make permissions non-case-sensitive, please add a comment with the instructions.  Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Compatible with all SDK versions (`android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` became `dangerous` permission in Android M and requires user to manually grant it).

In Android versions below Android M `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(...)` always returns `true` if you add these permission(s) in `AndroidManifest.xml`)

```
public void onSomeButtonClick() {
    ...
    if (!permissionsGranted()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 123);
    } else doLocationAccessRelatedJob();
    ...
}

private Boolean permissionsGranted() {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, @NonNull final String[] permissions, @NonNull final int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 123) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission granted.
            doLocationAccessRelatedJob();
        } else {
            // User refused to grant permission. You can add AlertDialog here
            Toast.makeText(this, "You didn't give permission to access device location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startInstalledAppDetailsActivity();
        }
    }
}

private void startInstalledAppDetailsActivity() {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I Had an strange issue and realized that the text of manifest permission has a a space character at the end. removed it and it is working just fine.

Before

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION "/>
```

After

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove s from the permission you are using sss you have to use ss